# How do I run a local command before starting SSH connection and after SSH connection closes?

Tags: bash, ssh

Essentially what I want to do is run a Bash script I created that switches WiFi SSIDs before starting the SSH connection, and after the SSH connection closes.

I have added this to `~/.ssh/config` by setting ProxyCommand to `./run-script; ssh %h:%p` but by doing this, I feel like it would ignore any parameters I passed when I run the ssh command. Also, I have no idea how to get the script to run again when the SSH connection closes.

Comment: why don't you create an alias?
    alias ssh_alias_name = /path/to/run-script && ssh

Comment: I can only suspect, that the `;` is taken literally. And I think the ProxyCommand should do it's post processing, when its internal remote pipe closes, that the command is supposed to establish. Essentially, you need to put the `ssh` invokation inside your `run-script` and pass all ssh tokens (like `%h` and `%p`) to your script.

Answer (score 4):

For OpenSSH you can specify a `LocalCommand` in your ssh config (`~/.ssh/config`).

But for that to work you also need the system-wide option (in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) `PermitLocalCommand` to `yes`. (By default it is set to `no`.)

It gets executed on the local machine after authenticating but before the remote shell is started.

There appears to be no (easy) way of executing something after the connection has been closed, though.

Comment: Does the command or background job it spawns get `SIGHUP` or some other signal upon disconnect? If so we could wait for that signal to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that it is not possible to implement a wrapper to 'ssh' (using alias, or some other method), it is possible to implement the following in the proxyCommand.

Important to note that there is no protection against multiple invocation of 'ssh' - possible that during a specific invocation that WIFI is already connected. Also, it is possible that when a specific ssh is terminated, the WIFI has to stay active because of other pending conditions.

Possible implementation of the proxy script is
ProxyCommand /path/to/run-script %h %p

```
#! /bin/sh
pre-command      # connect to WIFI
nc -N "$1" "$2"     # Tunnel, '%h' and '%p' are passed in
post-command     # Disconnect WIFI
```

You do not want to use simple ssh in the proxy script, as this will translate into another call to the 'run-script'. Also note that all options provided to the original ssh will be handled by the initial 'ssh' session that will be leveraging the proxy 'nc' tunnel.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have the pre-command and `nc` commands working but the post-command doesn't seem to be running. The script seems to be stopped as soon as `nc` is complete. Any way around that?

Comment: @silverAndroid - Adding '-N' to nc should help. Answered revised

Comment: I have a Mac and I don't think `-N` is the same on your machine as it is mine...[these are my options](https://pastebin.com/LPZ7VvAJ)

Comment: NC 1.10-41.1 (Linux Mint) has '-N Shutdown the network socket after EOF on stdin'. I do not have access to Mac.

Comment: As an alternative, consider 'socat (socat STDIO tcp4:$1:$2'. On my machine, it properly closed the socket on EOF. See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/512722/automatically-close-netcat-connection OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838811/alternative-for-netcat-utility